# Show tables status result

Tags: mysql, status

If I want to return only the result of one field from the result set of a SHOW TABLE STATUS command, for example "Auto_increment", what would the query look like?

Comment: Why do you need to know current autoincrement value?

Comment: read : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlshow.html

Comment: Try this - SELECT `AUTO_INCREMENT` FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'db1' AND TABLE_NAME = 'table1'

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM information_schema.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'db1' AND TABLE_NAME = 'table1'
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/tables-table.html
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html